# How to rank a table using for loop statement based on date without using pandas df.groupby and .rank?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, ranking, rank

I want to ask how to rank a table using a for-loop statement based on date. I can't use pandas df.groupby since I will be using it with other items for-loop statement.

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['Date'])['Cat'].rank(ascending=False)
```

This is the sample table.

```
        Cat Name    Date
    1   10  A   1/5/2021
    2   20  A   1/4/2021
    3   30  A   1/3/2021
    4   40  A   1/2/2021
    5   50  A   1/1/2021
    6   2   B   1/5/2021
    7   2   B   1/4/2021
    8   30  B   1/3/2021
    9   5   B   1/2/2021
    10  4   B   1/1/2021
    11  3   C   1/5/2021
    12  1   C   1/4/2021
    13  2   C   1/3/2021
    14  100 C   1/2/2021
    15  40  C   1/1/2021
    16  50  D   1/5/2021
    17  50  D   1/4/2021
    18  50  D   1/3/2021
    19  50  D   1/2/2021
    20  50  D   1/1/2021
```

I want to rank the column 'Cat' (Category) per date so that the result will be something like in the column 'Rank'

```
    Cat Name    Date    Rank
1   10  A   1/5/2021    2
2   20  A   1/4/2021    2
3   30  A   1/3/2021    2
4   40  A   1/2/2021    3
5   50  A   1/1/2021    1
6   2   B   1/5/2021    4
7   2   B   1/4/2021    3
8   30  B   1/3/2021    2
9   5   B   1/2/2021    4
10  4   B   1/1/2021    4
11  3   C   1/5/2021    3
12  1   C   1/4/2021    4
13  2   C   1/3/2021    4
14  100 C   1/2/2021    1
15  40  C   1/1/2021    3
16  50  D   1/5/2021    1
17  50  D   1/4/2021    1
18  50  D   1/3/2021    1
19  50  D   1/2/2021    2
20  50  D   1/1/2021    1
```

Again, thanks for the help. It is much appreciated.

Adding some inputs why I needed to rank it by date while using a for-loop statement by adding this table.

```
  Cat1 Name Date    Process Rank
1   10  A   1/5/2021    1   2
2   20  A   1/4/2021    1   2
3   30  A   1/3/2021    1   0
4   40  A   1/2/2021    0   3
5   50  A   1/1/2021    1   1
6   2   B   1/5/2021    1   0
7   2   B   1/4/2021    0   3
8   30  B   1/3/2021    1   0
9   5   B   1/2/2021    0   4
10  4   B   1/1/2021    1   0
11  3   C   1/5/2021    0   3
12  1   C   1/4/2021    1   0
13  2   C   1/3/2021    0   4
14  100 C   1/2/2021    1   0
15  40  C   1/1/2021    0   3
16  50  D   1/5/2021    1   1
17  50  D   1/4/2021    1   1
18  50  D   1/3/2021    1   1
19  50  D   1/2/2021    1   0
20  50  D   1/1/2021    0   0
```

For the process column, this is my excel command

```
=IF(F2<3,1,0)
```

If F2 (Rank Column) is less than 3, then 1 if otherwise 0

For the rank column, this is my excel command

```
=IF(E3=1, COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,B:B,">"&B2)+1,0)
```

If the previous date 'Process' Column is equal to 1, then rank it, otherwise 0

```
COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,B:B,">"&B2)+1
```

This is for ranking based on date in excel.

So, basically,
`Process = f(Rank)` and `Rank = f(previous day's Process, and rank of Cat per day)`.
I hope I was able to clear the question about the recursive and for-loop statement instead of using Pandas' groupby and rank.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow why you can't use `groupby`? Can you clarify?

Comment: I am using 'category' and 'rank' as part of the inputs of a recursive function based on previous dates (i+1) which can be solved by doing a for - loop statements.

Comment: I think more clarification is still needed in your question. The obvious answer is to use `groupby` and `rank` to make the rank column and continue from there. I'd add in the part you want to do next, this smells a little bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I added some additional statements on the bottom part of the question. I hope this will clear my intent. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, why does row 9 of your output have Rank=4? Row 10 has Rank=4 before adding Process so shouldn't the Process of row 10 = 0?

Comment: The table works from bottom to top (previous day to current day).